# Magento issue with calling isInStock() method on a product

Tags: php, magento

I want to check if some products are in stock but whatever I do the `isInStock()` method always returns `TRUE`. My products are configurable products with no associated products and under the "Inventory" tab "Stock Availability" is set to "Out of Stock".
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Please post the line of code you're using to check this.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Magento has a lot of history at this point, so it's a good idea to not always
trust that method names will do what "seems obvious".  Obvious now wasn't obvious a few years ago.

If you look at the following two methods on the Mage_Catalog_Model_Product class

```
public function isInStock()
{
    return $this->getStatus() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED;
}
public function getStatus()
{
    return $this->_getData('status');
}
```

You can see that `isInStock` checks the **status** attribute, set in the "General" section of the Product admin.

Try this instead

```
$stockItem = $product->getStockItem();
if($stockItem->getIsInStock())
{
    //in stock!
}
else
{
    //not in stock!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$qtyStock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();
```

Comment: This will only check the qty. However, the Stock Availability can be set to "Out of Stock" in magento. This will not check for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if ((int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty()>0) { ?>

 <?php  } else {} ?>
```

It worked for the simple product category view.

Comment: Is there any new in your answer compared to @Muk's answer?

Comment: Well, I just put them together. It turned out that it's useless.

Comment: Try to analyse other's answer whether your answer is same or not

Comment: I edited my answer, and put there the code that works for me.