# Use of magento is_in_stock

Tags: magento, product, stock

What exactly is the function of the property `is_in_stock` in Magento? Whether a product is in stock can be determined on whether `qty >= 1`?

It seems to automatically adjust to the current stock_level (compared to minimal allowed quantity?) but why then can you modify it manually? I feel like it has no use to modify it, because it will change to whatever it wants itself anyway..

I can't find a lot of information about the functionality of this property via google, so might be a good addition :-).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many smaller merchants will use Magento to monitor their actual "Warehouse" (spare room) stock levels for products.  There may be times where they want to temporarily have an item listed as out of stock on their web-store, but they will sto want the stock number in Magento to reflect the number of items they have on hand for other business reasons.

Put another way, the `is_in_stock` data member controls how the store displays the product, irrespective of how many items you have on hand.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I find odd about this though is that there  seems to be code that sets an item back in to stock when for example an order is canceled (`Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock->backItemQty`). So a small merchant would set `is_in_stock` to false and then an order is canceled (containing the product) and `is_in_stock` is true again?

Comment: Yes, it's a poorly implemented feature that's clearly the work of multiple teams not talking to one another.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to dig around: app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item.php

Possibly related post:
[Magento issue with calling isInStock() method on a product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701599/magento-problem-with-calling-isinstock-method-on-a-product)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The related post is also an odd thing, but not the problem I mean here :-)

Comment: Np, I'm interested in the difference as well, if you find the proper answer please post here if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Totally need to revamp my answer here so many apologies. When I looked at the function as it is defined in app/code/core/mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php I saw this very odd situation:

```
public function isInStock()
{
    return $this->getStatus() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED;
}
```

So as long as a product is Enabled, isInStock will always return true. The function for telling if a product is for sale is isSaleable().

Comment: That is correct but not the problem I'm mentioning here. I mean the StockItem's `is_in_stock` property and not the Product's.

Comment: Sorry about that, I got focused on the function and not the property. 

The example you mention above with manually setting "Out of Stock" then having the system turn it back to "in stock" when an order is canceled would only occur if the site has it's Manage Stock configuration set to yes. That can also be over-ridden at the product level within admin. We do this because we want inventory control of some products that we sell out of but not on others where we never sell out and inventory is less of a concern.