# Magento how to show out of stock in ONE category only while hiding them for all other categories?

Tags: magento

I am trying to display **out of stock** status for products in a specific category while hiding the status completely for all the other categories.

Presently, i have disabled showing stock status from inventory. So, any item that goes out of stock is hidden automatically.

Status Now:

1. All products whose inventory becomes 0 are automatically hidden.
2. when a product is in inventory it still does **not show** its status.
3. All products are **configurable** products.

what i want:

1. Have created a new category and added products to it. Only **simple** products are added to this category
2. I want to keep on showing this product even when inventory is 0
3. I want to display the status as **out of stock**
4. I want that this product is **not** add able to the cart. (this should automatically be possible because the product shall be out of stock.

Possible way forward:

As i see it,  I should enable display Stock Status from Inventory. By doing this, the product will still be visible after inventory becomes 0.... **But** this will be across **all categories**.. I only want this action for 1 category ???

Comment: Please check [this document about SO markdown for text/code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution. This may give you better idea.

```
<?php
if ($cat_id = '12')
{
    $collections = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->joinField(
        'qty',
        'cataloginventory/stock_item',
        'qty',
        'product_id=entity_id',
        '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
        'left'
    )
    ->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array('eq' => 0));

    foreach ($collections as $collection) {
    echo $collection->getData()->getName();
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple method would be to use Magento's ability to have custom layouts for each category.

1) Setup the store to show products even if out of stock

2) Create a new theme, which will override the base them you are using - it only needs to contain a copy of catalog/product/list.phtml

3) modify the original theme's list.phtml to only show items:

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <?php if( ! $_product->isInStock()) continue ?>
...
```

now you will have two themes, you base theme you are using, and then a new override theme with only the single file in there.

Now apply the new theme to the category you want the out of stock items shown on, and by default the original theme's listing view will skip products out of stock.

This could be done nicer using a Block override, which I would be happy to explain - but this is the simplest solution I can think of :-)

Comment: very simply explained... makes sense.. ill try it out. Thanks

Comment: andre...check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701599/magento-problem-with-calling-isinstock-method-on-a-product

Answer (score 0):

This is based on Andrew's answer. However, isInStock() seems to be always returning true. So I replaced it with isSaleable() like this:

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
   <?php if( ! $_product->isSaleable()) continue ?>
...
```

The answer is not the best, however, because you will still count the product in the total displayed items.

Answer (score 0):

i have modified the list.phtml to generate a query if a cat equals a given number.
with the query build grid/list

```
<?php
$_layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
$_category = $_layer->getCurrentCategory();
$_currentCategoryId= $_category->getId();
if($_currentCategoryId == 11):
?>
<div class="category-products">
    <?php  $stockCollection = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_in_stock', 0);

    $productIds = array();

    foreach ($stockCollection as $item) {
        $productIds[] = $item->getOrigData('product_id');
    }
    $categoryId = 11;
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
    $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addIdFilter($productIds)
        ->addCategoryFilter($category)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc');

    $products = array();?>



 <div class="category-products">
    <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php // List mode ?>
    <?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?>
    <?php $_iterator = 0; ?>
    <ol class="products-list" id="products-list">
    <?php foreach ($productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <li class="item<?php if( ++$_iterator == sizeof($productCollection) ): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
            <?php // Product Image ?>
            <p class="product-image">
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('ajax/product/quickview/id/' . $_product->getId()) ?>" rel="nofollow" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" class="ajax"><?php echo $this->__('Quick view') ?></a>
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>                
            </p>
            <?php // Product description ?>
            <div class="product-shop">
                <div class="f-fix">
                    <?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
                    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?></a></h2>
                    <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="desc std">
                        <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped ?>" class="link-learn"><?php echo $this->__('Learn More') ?></a>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="add-to-links">
                        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                            <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('products-list', 'none-recursive')</script>

    <?php else: ?>

    <?php // Grid Mode ?>

    <?php $_collectionSize = $productCollection->count() ?>
    <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
        <ul class="products-grid">
        <?php endif ?>
            <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                <p class="product-image">
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('ajax/product/quickview/id/' . $_product->getId()) ?>" rel="nofollow" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" class="ajax"><?php echo $this->__('Quick view') ?></a>
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                            <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                    </a>
                </p>
                <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
                <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                <div class="actions">
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <ul class="add-to-links">
                        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                            <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="toolbar-bottom">
        <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    </div>
</div>


<?php elseif(!$_productCollection->count()):
?>
<p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>

<?php else: ?>
<div class="category-products">
    <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
```