# How to not allow 0 quantity products in shoppingcart rule in Magento?

Tags: magento, shopping-cart, discount

I have set up shopping cart rule for 20% discount over $1000.
But I have to add one more condition for those products should not be included with quantity 0.

I have enabled backorder. So how can I add this product quantity is 0 or not in Shopping cart rule.

Please help

Comment: My suggestion is create  seperate script and run via cron every 30 mins.This script will check products with 0 stock and will remove discount rules or add exempt thiese product in discount rules.

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/q/2701599/2332721

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple conditions in Magento. Find the '+' button near the first condition and set the second condition that you want. It is as easy you can think of.

Comment: I know that. but there is no provision for check PRODUCT QUANTITY. That only allows to check cart item quantity and for that i am not looking for.